# Failed to resolve: de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.4.0

Tags: android, gradle

**Failed to resolve: de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.4.0**
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog

Comment: add your root levl `Build.Gradle`

Comment: As far as i see, there is no release of  2.4.0, make use of the latest release  **implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'**

Comment: https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dependencies` of `circleimageview` is **`2.2.0`** not **`2.4.0`**

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
}
```

Remove `de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.4.0` and use **`implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'`**

for more information check [**`circleimageview`**](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)

Comment: @TusharGujrathi happy to help you